# Finding contiguos subarray of equal sum

Tags: algorithm

```
Given array : 8 3 5 2 10 6 7 9 5 2
So the o/p will be Yes.
```

as: {8,3,5} {10,6} {9,5,2} they all have same sum value i.e. 16.

```
But for this array : 1 4 9 6 2 12
      o/p will be No.
```

as: No contiguous slide have same sum value

I was thinking to go with **SubSetSum Algorithm / Kadane Maximum SubArray Algorithm** but later I end up as all of the algorithms requires a target sum which is predefined. 
But here **we don't know the target sum**

Comment: You need to clean up this question.

Comment: Your question is unclear: is the desired sum value 16 given? If not, what criterion decides that you end up with value-16 sums and not e.g. value-8: {8} {3,5}? P.S. also something in your question formatting went wrong...

Comment: what about `{7,9}`?

Comment: `{1, 4, 9}` and `{2, 12}` ?

Comment: Theoretically the input array itself is a subarray, so it is a solution. I suppose there must be an additional condition that you want at least two subarrays. But then still `{2},{2}`, `{5,2},{5,2}` and `{8},{3,5}` would all be solutions for the first example. You have also not mentioned whether negative values are allowed. So the problem is not well defined.

Comment: mishadoff you just have to print Yes or No...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If desired sum is given, and all subarrays should be contiguous, then it's easily can be done in `O(n)`.

Run a loop over array and maintain boundaries of slices (`left` and `right` indexes) and `currentSum`.

Start with first element as a 0. Boundaries will be [0, 0] (for simplicity we include right). Then in a loop you have three conditions.

1. If sum is less than desired, add right element to the sum and advance right index
2. If sum is greater than desired, remove left element from the sum and advance left index
3. If sum is equal to given, print the slice. To avoid this slice in next iteration, advance left index and adjust the sum.

Translated to code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int givenSum = 16;
        int[] a = new int[] {8, 3, 5, 2, 10, 6, 7, 9, 5, 2};

        // boundaries of slice
        int left = 0; // defines position of slice
        int right = 0; // exclusive
        int currentSum = 0;

        while (right < a.length) {

            if (currentSum < givenSum) { // sum is not enough, add from the right
                currentSum += a[right];
                right++;
            }

            if (currentSum > givenSum) { // sum exceeds given, remove from the left
                currentSum -= a[left];
                left++;
            }

            if (currentSum == givenSum) { // boundaries of given sum found, print it
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, left, right)));
                // remove the left element, so we can process next sums
                currentSum -= a[left];
                left++;
            }
        }

    }
```

For your case it prints 4 slices which yields sum 16

```
[8, 3, 5]
[10, 6]
[7, 9]
[9, 5, 2]
```

**EDIT:**

As OP clarified, no given sum available, the goal is to check if there are at least two different contiguous subarrays present which yields equal sum.

The most straightforward algorithm is to generate all possible sums and check if there are duplicates

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 4, 9, 6, 2, 12};

HashSet<Integer> sums = new HashSet<>();
int numOfSums = 0;

for (int left = 0; left < a.length - 1; left++) {
    for (int right = left; right < a.length; right++) {
        // sum from left to right
        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = left; k <= right; k++) {
            sum += a[k];
        }
        numOfSums++;
        sums.add(sum);
    }
}
System.out.println(sums.size() == numOfSums);
```

Complexity of this is `O(n^3)`, not a good one, but works.

Hint: One trick could be explored to boost it to `O(n^2)`, you don't need to calculate sum for every pair of slices!

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work and for some extent it's really so much helpful. But in the problem we don't know the target sum and that is the main problem. Again thank you for the code it's a great piece of work I must agree.

Comment: @AndrewWatson then the problem is even simpler, calculate all possible sums of contiguous arrays and check duplicates

Comment: I am not sure this solution always works. When I test with a limit case list = [0,0,0] and sums = 0 it does not work because it gives 3 subarrays while we have here all possible subarrays ([0], [0], [0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0,0]) that sum up to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

1. You have the total sum = 48
2. Now the each subset would have a sum which would be equal to a factor of 48. The smaller the factor the more number of subsets you can break it into
3. For all factors of the sum, check if the answer is possible for that factor or not. This can be done in O(n) by simply traversing the array.
4. Time Complexity would be O(n * factors(sum))

Comment: how about array {5,1,1,4,2}..sum is 13, so no factor...but {5,1} and {4,2} equals 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming to find all sub-sums of the array, then find the sub array with same sum. The complexity should be O(n2).

```
    void subsum(int n, int* arr, int** sum) {
         for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
              sum[i][i] = arr[i];
         }
         for (int l = 2; l <= n; ++l) {
              for (int i = 0; i < n - l + 1; ++i) {
                   sum[i][i + l - 1] = sum[i][i + l - 2] + arr[i + l -1];
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: This is SUBSET SUM algorithm..how can you find the slices?